# Axios how to add property to array of objects

Tags: javascript, axios

How can I add a userRating property of null to an array of objects using axios?

This is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
 const movieRequest = () => {
    axios
      .get(key)
      .then((response) => {
        const updatedResponse = response.data
        updatedResponse.map((movie) => ({
          ...movie,
          userRating: null,
        }))
        setMovieList(updatedResponse)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` returns a new array and does not mutate the array on which it is called. You just need to change your function to:

```
.then((response) => {
    const updatedResponse = response.data.map((movie) => ({
       ...movie,
       userRating: null,
    }));
    setMovieList(updatedResponse);
})
```

Comment: Well, the console.log returns this: TypeError: response.data.map is not a function

Comment: If it's Axios it'll probably something stupid like `response.data.data`. Try logging the response in the console and debugging it. @bysiuxvx.

Comment: Make sure that `response.data` is not undefined and that `data` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

.map returns a new array, you need to assign it to a variable.

const mapped = updatedRespone.map....
setMovieList(mapped)